# Xpages File Download Control sort column

Tags: file, download, controls, xpages

I would like to have a File Download control display the attachments with the newest (latest) Created On date at the top. The default is to display the newest last.

```xml
<xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="FD"
    displayLastModified="false" value="#{document1.files}"
    style="width:98%" hideWhen="false"
    displayType="true" allowDelete="false" displayCreated="true">
</xp:fileDownload>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there's currently no better answer, I'll post one here.

Actually, the `<xp:fileDownload>` component lists file attachments in order they appear in document's Rich Text field, not the newest last:
[image]

You can't change this behavior with any of the properties, so the one possible way is to obtain the list of attachments, sort it like you need, and then feed the sorted list to `<xp:repeat>` component, where you can draw the attachment table that will just slightly or even not differ from that displayed by `<xp:fileDownload>`. It's not that hard, just look at created HTML markup in your browser debug tool and recreate that inside your `<xp:repeat>`.

Suppose you have `dominoData` declared on your page:

```xml
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1"
        documentId="9CAA72D47AEA7C8D462582FB005AB525"
        action="openDocument" />
</xp:this.data>
```

Then create the `<xp:panel>` where your `<xp:repeat>` will reside. Create the `dataContext` for your panel:

```xml
<xp:panel>
    <xp:this.dataContexts>
        <xp:dataContext var="attachments">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
                #{javascript:
                    var sourceList:java.util.List = document1.getAttachmentList('files');
                    if (sourceList.size() == 0) {
                        return sourceList;
                    }
                    java.util.Collections.sort(sourceList, createdComparator);
                    return sourceList;
                }
            ]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:dataContext>
    </xp:this.dataContexts>
</xp:panel>
```

There you get a list of `com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.AttachmentValueHolder` objects, then sort the list with declared Comparator (see update below) using the `created` file attribute, and return the sorted list as `attachments` variable.

Then you create `<xp:repeat>` and nest it inside your `<xp:panel>` after `<xp:dataContexts>`. Give it the `dataContext`'s variable name as a `value`:

```xml
<xp:repeat value="#{attachments}" var="attachment">
    <xp:text value="#{attachment.type}" />
    <xp:label value=" - " />
    <xp:text>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
            #{javascript:
                var rawSize = attachment.getLength();
                return (rawSize < 1024 ? 1 : (rawSize / 1024).toFixed(0)) + " KB";
            }
        ]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
    <xp:label value = " - " />
    <xp:link text="#{attachment.name}" value="#{attachment.href}" />
    <xp:label value = " - " />
    <xp:text>
        <xp:this.value>
            #{javascript:
                return new java.util.Date(attachment.getCreated());
            }
        </xp:this.value>
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime type="both" timeStyle="short" />
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:text>
    <xp:br />
</xp:repeat>
```

Here's the result of `<xp:repeat>` output compared to `<xp:fileDownload>`:
[image]

Just create the markup that looks like `fileDownload`'s table, and you're done.

> Update

It's worth the effort to create a request scoped Managed Bean that will serve as the Comparator instead of implementing some good sorting algorithm right inside SSJS code block.

Create a Java class inside Code/Java folder under some existing or new package. If the package name is e.g. `com.benway.util` and the class name is `CreatedComparator`:

```java
package com.benway.util;

import java.util.Comparator;
import com.ibm.xsp.model.FileRowData;

public class CreatedComparator implements Comparator<FileRowData> {

    public int compare(FileRowData file1, FileRowData file2) {
        if (file1 == null || file2 == null) return 0;
        return (int)(file2.getCreated() - file1.getCreated());
    }
}
```

Register your new class as a managed bean in your `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>createdComparator</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>
            com.benway.util.CreatedComparator
        </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    ...etc...
</faces-config>
```

Now you're really done :)

Comment: That looks like a good solution that would work, but I've gone too far down the road with a viewPanel. There are too many other programmatic things tied in. In the next project, I'd pursue the way you have done it.